# jQuery: Cannot animate transform css for an element

Tags: jquery, css

I have created the following function to animate a div so it slightly moves to the left and then moves to the right:

```
var jiggle_pull_chain = function(){

    var $pull_chain = jQuery("#pull-chain");

    $pull_chain.animate({
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(3deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(3deg)',
                    'transform': 'rotate(3deg)',
                    'zoom': 1
        }, 5000);

    $pull_chain.animate({
                    '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-3deg)',
                    '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-3deg)',
                    'transform': 'rotate(-3deg)',
                    'zoom': 1
        }, 5000);


};
```

For some reason, the CSS properties are not added to the element and no javascript errors are received. Anybody know if I'm doing this right?

[Here](http://versacreative.com.php53-9.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/) is a test page where the code is used (towards the bottom of the page).

Here is the entire code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//Clicking on employee name 
$(".employee-names a").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    //Find the employee id
    var employee_id = $this.data('employee-id');

    //Hide all employee images
    hide_employee_imgs();

    //Loop through all employees and reveal their first image matching this id
    $(".employee").each(function(){
        var img_employee_id = $(this).data('employee-id');
        if ( img_employee_id == employee_id ) {
            $(this).find('img:first-child').fadeIn('fast');
            return false;
        }
    });
});

//pull-chain for the team section
$("#pull-chain .handle").on("click", function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $pull_chain = $this.prev();

    if ( $this.hasClass('pulled') ) {
        $pull_chain.animate({ height: 150}, 600);
        $this.removeClass('pulled');
        switch_employee_img();
    }
    else{
        $this.addClass('pulled');
        $pull_chain.animate({ height: 230}, 600);
        switch_employee_img();
    }
});

});

var hide_employee_imgs = function(){
jQuery(".employee img").hide();
};

var switch_employee_img = function(){
jQuery(".employee img").each(function(){
    $this = jQuery(this);
    if ( $this.is(":visible") ) {
        $this.hide();
        $this.siblings().fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
    }
}); 

jiggle_pull_chain();
};

var jiggle_pull_chain = function(){

var $pull_chain = jQuery("#pull-chain");

$pull_chain.animate({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(3deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotate(3deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(3deg)',
                'zoom': 1
    }, 5000);

$pull_chain.animate({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-3deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-3deg)',
                'transform': 'rotate(-3deg)',
                'zoom': 1
    }, 5000);


};
```

Comment: that's true. So you may have to use CSS transition and use `.css` method to change the transform instead.

Comment: I even tried it that way: `$(this).css('transform','rotate(3deg)');` still didn't work.

Comment: If possible, can create jsfiddle ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
$pull_chain.animate({  textIndent: 0 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      jQuery(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(-3deg)'); 
      jQuery(this).css('-ms-transform','rotate(-3deg)'); 
      jQuery(this).css('transform','rotate(-3deg)'); 
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');

$pull_chain.animate({  textIndent: 0 }, {
    step: function(now,fx) {
      jQuery(this).css('-webkit-transform','rotate(3deg)'); 
      jQuery(this).css('-ms-transform','rotate(3deg)'); 
      jQuery(this).css('transform','rotate(3deg)'); 
    },
    duration:'slow'
},'linear');
```